# Regarding http post request to url (Kibana 8.6.2) to get the endpoint response

Tags: python, elasticsearch, post, http-post, kibana-7

Earlier I was using kibana version 7.10.2 and used to get a http response via inspect and going under network tab and http request- "es" with

```
curl "http://url:5601/kibana/internal/search/es"
```

and get the raw data to give a input in automated script then convert it to JSON string and recently its upgraded to version 8.6.2 and now the http request I get is `bsearch?compress=true` with

```
curl "http://url:5601/internal/bsearch?compress=true"
```

which I found out to be compressed response to reduce the network load and its response is some encoded string which I cannot convert to JSON string however.
Is there any options to get reach the es endpoint?

earlier http request

[image]

newer http request

[image]

I got some encoded string from `request.post(url, headers=header, data=httpData, auth =('username','password'))` after the upgrade and I tried decoding it to JSON String but result was some unformatted error string.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the endpoint you were using to retrieve data from Elasticsearch has changed with the upgrade to Kibana 8.6.2, and the response is now compressed to reduce network load. In order to convert the compressed response to JSON string, you can use the gzip library in Python.
Here's an example code snippet that you can use to retrieve the data and convert the compressed response to JSON string:

```
import requests
import gzip
import json

url = 'http://url:5601/internal/bsearch?compress=true'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'kbn-xsrf': 'true',
    'Authorization': 'Basic <base64 encoded username:password>'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=your_data)

# decode the response using gzip
decoded_content = gzip.decompress(response.content)

# convert the decoded content to JSON string
json_string = json.loads(decoded_content)
```

Make sure to replace your_data with the appropriate data that you want to send in the POST request, and also replace  with your actual username and password encoded in base64 format.

Hope this helps!